# How to overwrite datetimepicker enabledHours after initial load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

On page load I initialized datetimepicker to this:

```
$('#txtdate').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true,
    maxDate: someDate,
    minDate: curentDate,
    enabledHours: HoursArray(CurrentDayOpenTime, CurrentDayCloseTime)
});
```

but on new date selection I want to update/overwrite **`enabledHours`** (because on new date `enabledHours` are different) using below function.

```
$(document).on('dp.change', manipulateTime);

//function////

function manipulateTime(td){
    if (!td.date.isSame(td.oldDate, "day")) {
        $('#txtdate').datetimepicker({
            inline: true,
            sideBySide: true,
            maxDate: SomeCloseDate,
            minDate: SelectedDayOpenTime,
            enabledHours: HoursArray(SelectedDayOpenTime, SelectedDayCloseTime)
        });
    }
}
```

I couldn't able to overwrite the previous **`enabledHours`**. It always shows enabled hours which is generated on page load.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I would be interested to know what  td.date & td.oldDate return in function manipulateTime

Comment: @inspired  can you suggest on this?

Comment: @RohitasBehera - td.date = "Tue Oct 24 2017 09:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" and td.oldDate = "Wed Oct 18 2017 11:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code to change [`enabledHours`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#endisabledhours):

```
$(document).on('dp.change', manipulateTime);

function manipulateTime(td){
   //Your code.... 
   $('#txtdate').data('DateTimePicker').enabledHours([21,22,23]); //change the array of enabled hours here
}
```